# How to create dynamic route in Apigee Edge based on path and verb?

Tags: apigee

I am trying to define dynamic route in Apigee Edge, but not able to define one, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must be referring to the conditional flows in the proxy endpoint, that way you can specify both verb and path to be checked in the preflow.

Please refer to http://docs.apigee.com/api-services/content/flow-variables-and-conditions for more details.

Comment: Abhijeet lets get a simple example of a policy that might do this; if the doc link changes, the information will be lost.